# Getting length of a String in java generics

Tags: java, generics

I am learning java generics, and i was trying to write a very simple code, which has to print the type of parameter, in my case just for show purpose i am trying only String type,it was fine till i printed the class of the type, but for string type when i used .length() to get the length of my string,it showed an error:

> cannot find symbol
>   System.out.println(obj1.length()); //dosen't work

since the class is **class java.lang.String**, why can't we use .length() in generics?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class GenericMethodTest {
   public static < E > void sumOfGenericValues(E obj1, E obj2) {
     System.out.println(obj1.getClass());
      System.out.println(obj1.length()); //dosen't work
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String fn = "JK", ln = "Rowling";
      sumOfGenericValues(fn, ln);
   }
}
```

Comment: How would the compiler know that? It sees only the generic types. You could also call the method with an ``Integer`` and then there is no ``length()`` method. So the compiler has to take the least common denominator, which is ``Object``.

Comment: `<E> void sumOfGenericValues(E obj1, E obj2)` means "this function accepts **any** input, so long as both objects are of the same type". This means the function can only call methods that are common to all Objects, i.e. those defined in [java.lang.Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html). This does not include `length()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you know it's a `String`, but the compiler and the method cannot know what are gonna receive as Type argument.

You can edit your method so if it's receiving a String, it will print its lenght.
For doing that you must first cast the object into a String, so you can use the String methods.

```
 public static < E > void sumOfGenericValues(E obj1, E obj2) {
        System.out.println(obj1.getClass());
        if(obj1 instanceof String) {
            System.out.println(((String)obj1).length());
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method doesn't ensure that it's receiving a `String`.
You can ensure to receive a `String` by changing your type parameter `E` to `E extends String`

Example:

```
public static <E extends String> void sumOfGenericValues(E obj1, E obj2) {
    System.out.println(obj1.length());
    System.out.println(obj2.length());
}
```

Comment: Note: not the best example: `String` is `final`,  it cannot be extended anyway, could use `String` directly... but OK for given question

Comment: Yes, was about to edit that sentence too. But I think this is what he was really looking for and not an `instanceof` check